# Any way to access organisational data?

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, organization-browser

I would like to access the data that feeds the  'organisation chart/structure' web part in SP 13 online. Preferably JavaScript. I can't find any reference to any part of the api that would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of this is powered by the user profiles and the Manager field.

Here is an article page on MSDN with code examples:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj920104.aspx

Sample code from the reference:

```
var userProfileProperties;

// Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');

function getUserProperties() {

// Replace the placeholder value with the target user's credentials.
var targetUser = "domainName\\userName";

// Get the current client context and PeopleManager instance.
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

// Specify the properties to retrieve and target user for the 
// UserProfilePropertiesForUser object.
var profilePropertyNames = ["PreferredName", "Department"];
var userProfilePropertiesForUser = 
    new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(
        clientContext,
        targetUser,
        profilePropertyNames);

// Get user profile properties for the target user.
// To get the value for only one user profile property, use the
// getUserProfilePropertyFor method.
userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(
    userProfilePropertiesForUser);

// Load the UserProfilePropertiesForUser object and send the request.
clientContext.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call succeeds.
function onRequestSuccess() {
    var messageText = "\"PreferredName\" property is " 
        + userProfileProperties[0];
    messageText += "<br />\"Department\" property is " 
        + userProfileProperties[1];
    $get("results").innerHTML = messageText;
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call fails.
function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
    $get("results").innerHTML = "Error: " + args.get_message();
}
```